# Configuration tomcat7 for normaly work

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I decided to start app directly from tomcat server. 
I have part of configuration in web.xml and more part as spring security,web, and ect by java configs. When build war file, put into tomcat wars folders and started project and tried to sign in, i have 404 error. what went wrong?
Tomcat 7

Comment: you have to be more specific. Can you post tomcat log to see what happens?

Comment: So. Without giving us **any** detail about any of your files you expect us to offer you a solution? Being as we are not magic, the only solution we can offer is to read the documentation.

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Oct/2015:12:16:28 +0300] "POST /j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 404 997